# IN Solr, What is the diffrent between "*" and "[* TO *]"

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I need to make return all Documents which has field and not empty.

I tried `field_is:[* TO *]` and `field_is:*`, and without different in result.

So is it the both are equivalent?

Comment: Initial guess is that `field:*` wasn't valid syntax earlier and were added as returning all documents with a value in that field later. There's a small technical difference - `[* TO *]` gets wrapped in a SolrRangeQuery, while the other one doesn't.